# React Native: Elevation Style Property - Change shadow direction

Tags: android, react-native, styles, shadow, elevation

Can I change the shadow direction of elevation style property (android only) on React Native?

Typically the shadow is show on bottom of element, but I wanna show it on top side.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about Android (which I'm going to assume since `elevation` doesn't exist on iOS), no you can't.

The virtual 'creating' the shadows are coming from fixed light spots for now (See https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/environment.html#environment-light-shadow).